# ClickTag working for the top layer button, but not for buttons on the layers underneath

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, flash-cs5, clicktag

I have a Flash stage with various buttons, each on a different layer. The top-most layer contains only actions. In this layer on the last frame I have all the clickTAGs listed:

```
inst_prod1.onRelease = function () { 
    getURL (_root.clickTAG1, "_blank"); 
}

inst_prod2.onRelease = function () { 
    getURL (_root.clickTAG2, "_blank"); 
}

inst_prod3.onRelease = function () { 
    getURL (_root.clickTAG3, "_blank"); 
}

inst_btn.onRelease = function () { 
    getURL (_root.clickTAG4, "_blank"); 
}
```

Having tested the clickTAGs, the inst_btn instance is working correctly, none of the others call the clickTAG when clicked. inst_btn is located on the layer directly below the actions layer at the top.

I think I may have to do something with specifying a path as it's not on the top level, but I don't understand how to implement this. I'm using Flash CS5 and ActionScript 2.

I am aware that I can create a layer on top with invisible buttons. I have used this method before. But then my hover effects on the actual buttons don't work.

Comment: The position of the layer in which the buttons are located only matters if they overlap, never to retrieve a variable at the _root level. Please make sure the functions are being actually called by setting a line like: trace("onRelease inst_prod1 "+_root.clickTAG1) on each and check if the clickTAG value is correct.

Comment: Yes, after testing it seems that nothing is firing from the onRelease event. Not sure why that could be.